# Creating a string of a specific size (in bytes)

Tags: java, string, byte

I have an application where I want to have a method that creates a string of a specified size in bytes.

here's what I basically wrote. I just want to make sure that this produces for example a string of **size** bytes

```
    static String createMsg(int size){

    byte[] msgB= new byte[size];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        msgB[i] = 105;
    }
    String x = new String(msgB);


    return x; 
 }
```

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the number of bytes in a string? It depends on an encoding.

Comment: if you care about binary data instead of characters you probably should use `ByteBuffer` instead of `String`

Comment: Once you convert your bytes to String, you're no longer with that exact quantity of bytes because Java will use UTF-16 as it's default encoding. If you're intending to save them to a file, you should not convert it to String, you should use the bytes array you already have or a ByteBuffer as @the8472 suggested.

Comment: Unlike in C, in Java a String does not hold bytes.  Any attempt to force a String to hold bytes is likely to cause data corruption.  For example, if your system's default charset is UTF-8 (which most non-Windows sytems are), and if your byte value were 205 instead of 105, the String created by `new String(msgB)` would contain question marks or Unicode replacement characters.

Answer (score 0):

To create a string of a specific size in byte, you must create a string only containing ASCII characters. All characters between `0x0` (0) and `0x7F` (127) are ASCII characters and each ASCII character takes one byte. It takes even one byte, if our encoding is UTF, as the first 128 characters in UTF and ASCII are the same for compatiblity reasons.

You can also rely on Apache Commons 3 and use this code snippet to generate a string of a specific size.

```java
RandomStringUtils.randomAscii(100);
```